# The "election" banner is now on meta only. Is that the correct behavior?

Tags: discussion, election

I'm just curious. Since last week I have seen the message "Please participate in the Unix and Linux 2011 community moderator election" on both our main site and meta. Today the banner disappears on the main site. Is this by design? What's the logic behind that?

Answer (score 2):

The banner is a little obnoxious so we don't like to leave it up for too long.

Anyone who is eligible to vote in the election gets an *unavoidable* notification message in their queue, so if they *visited the site at all in the election period*, believe me, they know about the election.

The banner is mostly for average users who wander by, and most of them will not terribly care that we're having an election -- and for power users, the banner gets very old, very rapidly. Worse, if there are too many banners, you have "boy who cried wolf" and everyone ignores it.

Thus, we try very hard to use site level banners as infrequently as possible. There are several during any election, and we think that's sufficient.